# Battlefield 1 unbind spotting key q in planes

Tags: battlefield-1

How can you unbind the <kbd>q</kbd> key for spotting while in planes (or in vehicles)?

I use my <kbd>q</kbd> and <kbd>e</kbd> keys for rolling, but this interferes with spotting.

Comment: Have you tried rebinding the keys in-game? Does it give you that option?

Comment: I tried, unfortunately you can only unbind/rebind it globally, meaning I can't spot with q when I'm on foot.

Comment: As lame as this sounds, you may have to stick to one or the other when you're playing, especially if DICE didn't include the different setups like in BF4. I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: Is there another key you can globally bind to spot in the mean time? Like a side mouse button?